# Hi ! need help in choice of class with a customer - appointment table

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to build a "customer" menu textbased to make automatic appointments and manage conflicts. I'm using Python but so far I've been using procedural programming (I'm a newbie), but it's getting too complicated to maintain. I would like to use a CSV file to keep all the contact (up to a thousand) and calcurse to manage my calendar.

Basically, I would like to check if the contact is approved and then send him my availabilities. I try to use the datefinder module to get a date & time, check if available, and ask for the order.

I'd like to know what class I need to create:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time

class Contact:
    def __init__(self, index, name, last_time, last_level='unreliable', appdate=None, apporder=None, appnote=None):
        self.index = index
        self.name = name
        self.last_time = last_time #last time I received a message from this person to unlogg if it's 
                                    over 5min agoo
        self.last_level = last_level # can be unreliable,main,date,order,note as
                                     # unreliable= don't even send availibities
                                     # main=the person is logged send availibities
                                     # date=ask for date, order=ask for order, note=ask for note
        self.appdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(appdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').date()
        self.apporder = apporder
        self.appnote = appnote

class Appointment:
 # I'd like to create a class for all the appointments from the calcurse file listing all the appointments to be able to check for instances if any conflicts with any new appointments.

    def __init__(self, name, appdate, apporder, appnote):
        self.name = name
        self.appdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(appdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.apporder = apporder
        self.appnote = appnote

def find_contact_in_file(name):
    try:
        with open("contact", 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            index = 0
            for line in reader:
                index += 1
                if line[0] == name:
                    print(index, line)
                    contact = Contact(index, line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5])
                    return contact
            return contact.Contact(index + 1, name, int(time.time()), "unreliable", None, None, None)
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```

Do I need a class Reply to make the reply from the message I get from the customer?

Comment: I think a freelancer is a better option than stackoverflow:)

Comment: So I don't fully understand your question but
I would use a database(MongoDB or tinydb) for storing the data rather than a CSV-file